# UIDocument saveToURL did override existing file

Tags: objective-c, nsdocument

i'm currently saving a UIDocument with the following code:

```
[pdfDatei saveToURL:self.fileurl forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
/* ... */
 }];
```

fileurl is a local file with a automatic generated filename (xyz_20141208_1659.ext) and i run into following problem. It is possible, that two files will get the same filename and UIDocument did override the old file without any error. Are there any options to let run saveToURL into a error when the file already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Before writing, check if the file already exists, and present a "already exists do you want to overwrite popup".